# ArrangeOverride and Arrange() when are they called by the Layouting system?

Tags: layout, silverlight-4.0, measureoverride, arrangeoverride

I am trying to understand the layout system in [Silverlight](https://www.microsoft.com/silverlight/), but I don't really know how the process works. I know that Measure is always called before and then when all the measures have been done the `arrange` starts. But when exactly does this process start, and are we able to control it?

Please don't write MSDN library link, I have already read it, and it's not clear at all.

My specific situation is that I have some nested `LinearLayouts` (inherit a class from `Panel` and `Arrangeoverride` and `MEasureoverride` work) but I need the `rootcontainer` size (because their sizes are percentages of the parent), and I can't get it until all the elements are loaded in the tree, so I call `arrange()` in LayoutRoot_Loaded. It works, yes, but It does the layout process like 3 times and that is not efficient for the whole system...
Can anybody help or at least explain how the layout system can be totally managed by the programmer? :-)

Answer (score 0):

can you try to put your code inside

```
    private void LayoutRoot_SizeChanged(object sender, System.Windows.SizeChangedEventArgs e)
    {
    }
```

rather than calling Arrange()?